# How could I find what is blocking outgoing packet with destination port 25

Tags: windows-7, port

There is something block outgoing packet that has destination port 25 inside my computer. I cannot open TCP connection on port 25 to any IP address including loop-back IP, even I already disabled Windows Firewall.

I have tried capture the packet using Wireshark, I didn't see any port 25 packet.

It's not the router's issue. If I telnet to port 25 from the VM running by VirtualBox running on my computer with bridged adapter configuration. I can connect successfully.

If I boot up the Windows in Safe Mode with Networking Support, I also can connect successfully.

How can I find out what is blocking this port?

Here is the error message from telnet command

```
telnet [IP ADDRESS] 25
Connecting To [IP ADDRESS]...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

My OS is MS Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

**Update:**

- The destination address has SMTP service running on port 25.
- I succeeded telnet from my VM to that address, proves that it's not the routing problem between my PC and the destination address.
- I can ping the destination address. It's not the routing problem, this problem happens event the destination address is 127.0.0.1.
- Tracert look correctly.

Comment: What does `netstat -a -o` show for port 25? You'll be given a PID which you'll be able to find from `Task Manager`.

Comment: Your command prints out all active connections. I don't see any of them show port 25.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of your setup, also, as it's not clear what's hosting services. For example, does your "host" OS have the service you're trying to connect to on port 25? If not, is the service external (over the Internet)?

Comment: Can you `ping` your target site? You will get the same error whether the problem is with the port or the routing to the site, and this will differentiate the two cases (unless `ping` is disabled on the target site). You can make sure that `ping` is enabled, by repeating the `ping` from the VM when the connection is established. You could also compare `netstat` and `tracert` from the working and failing connections.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I just updated my question adding answer for your questions.